# Github Actions python build error: "AttributeError: __enter__"

Tags: python, github-actions, github-secret

I have a webscraper that runs locally, and puts the data in a mysql database hosted on filess.io. Wanted to set up a schedule on github actions to run it consistently, but the build fails here:

```
 try:
    with connect(
        host=DB_HOST,
        user=DB_USER,
        password=DB_PASSWORD,
        database=DB_DATABASE,
        port=DB_PORT
    ) as connection:
        print(connection)
```

With this error:

```
0s
Run python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 66, in <module>
    with connect(
AttributeError: __enter__
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have secrets set up in github, and the values are pulled into the code in this earlier section, with no errors:

```
try:
    DB_HOST=os.environ["DB_HOST"]
    DB_USER=os.environ["DB_USER"]
    DB_PASSWORD=os.environ["DB_PASSWORD"]
    DB_DATABASE=os.environ["DB_DATABASE"]
    DB_PORT=os.environ["DB_PORT"]
```

This code works perfectly on my local machine, with secrets saved in .env file. I have double- and triple-checked that my secrets are set in github. Am I missing something?

I tried running locally (worked fine), logging the github secrets to verify they were stored correctly (was obscured, so that didn't work). Looked up the **enter** error, and it means some attribute has an error, but I can't figure out which.

Main point of confusion: it works locally. This leads me to believe it's an error with my github setup. Any ideas what's going on?

EDIT: adding github actions workflow code below:

```
name: Manual workflow
on: [workflow_dispatch]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      - name: checkout repo content
        uses: actions/checkout@v2 # checkout the repository content to github runner

      - name: setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.9' # install the python version needed

      - name: install python packages
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: execute py script # run main.py
        env:
          DB_HOST: ${{ secrets.DB_HOST }}
          DB_USER: ${{ secrets.DB_USER }}
          DB_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }}
          DB_DATABASE: ${{ secrets.DB_DATABASE }}
          DB_PORT: ${{ secrets.DB_PORT }}
        run: python main.py
```

Comment: Please add your relevant GHA workflow to your question. Thanks!

Comment: The `connect` is failing while establishing a connection with MySQL but there's no setup/config to start the MySQL (not the instance on that machine or via Docker using `services`).

Comment: I'm using these imports in main.py:  
  
`'import mysql.connector  
from mysql.connector import connect, Error`  
  
which makes my code similar to the first example here:   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html  
  
Is there more setup/config needed to connect to MySQL? The code works when I run it locally.

Answer (score 0):

After much digging, my requirements.txt had mysql-connector listed, which is deprecated. My local system had mysql-connector-python installed and was using that. Not sure how the requirements.txt file added the wrong one. Adding mysql-connector-python to the requirements.txt fixed this particular bug.

Thanks to @Azeem for your debugging help!

Comment: You're welcome! To avoid such dependency issues in the future, you should start using a virtual environment for your Python projects e.g. [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). That'll help contain your dependencies. Good luck!